# What's the meaning and grammar of 'while to'?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> As you say, replied ,Polemarchus: besides, there will be a night-festival, which it will be worth **while to** look at. We will rise after dinner, and go out to see this festival; and there we shall meet with many of our young men, with whom we can converse. Therefore stay, and do not refuse us. - The Republic of Plato

I've never seen a sentence which has no verb after conjunction while. Is it okay grammatically? And what's the meaning?

I presume it means "during looking at"

Comment: See [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worthwhile)

Comment: @user178049 Thank you. Why is there a space there?

Comment: All these versions are fine: worthwhile, worth-while, and worth while. You can read more about it in Cambridge Guide to English Usage on page 583.

Comment: You are welcome, but can you access that book?

Comment: @user178049 I got a pdf file easily from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no phrase like "while to". Nor is the while a conjunction in the sentence presented. In fact, the "to" is part of the to-infinitive "to look".  The phrase "worth while" has been used in place of the adjective "worthwhile"

You can use either the adjective worthwhile + to do something or the phrase worth while + to do something, without any difference in meaning.
However, the former is far more common.